# About pH of an aqueous solution of SO2

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, equilibrium, aqueous-solution, solutions, ph

Probably we can have an aqueous solution of $\ce{SO2}$ by dissolving it in water, because we would have an equilibrium between $\ce{SO2(g)}$ and $\ce{SO2(aq)}$:

$$\ce{SO2(g) <=> SO2(aq)}$$

- How can I compare pH of an aqueous solution of $\ce{SO2}$ with that of pure water qualitatively?
- What happens to the pH of an aqueous solution of $\ce{SO2}$ if I aerate it by bubbling air through it?

Comment: 1. Is $\ce{SO2}$ an acidic, basic, or neutral oxide? 2. Can $\ce{SO2}$ react with any of the gasses in air, and if so, what is the product?

Comment: @  Nicolau Saker Neto: I know that So2 is acidic.And I could assume that I would react with gases, since it is a gas.But how can I relate this?

Comment: If $\ce{SO2}$ is an acidic oxide, then which acid does it create when reacting with water, and what is its name? How strong is this acid? Also, notice that this acid is *very similar*, in formula and name, to another compound which has one extra atom . What is this compound? Could the extra atom come from air? What would the reaction be?

Comment: @  Nicolau Saker Neto: When SO2  dissolve in water ,H2SO3  will be the acid that is going to form, it is known as sulphurous acid . And is that extra atom is H or any other?

Comment: Think of the most common elements in air, and try adding them to the formula for sulphurous acid. Which do you think is the most likely outcome?

Comment: @  Nicolau Saker Neto: Should I add  or subtract that particular element?.Is it HSO3-

Comment: You have to add an atom present in large amounts in air to $\ce{H2SO3}$. Can you think of a familiar formula that would result from this? If you don't get it right, no worries, I'll tell you the answer.

Comment: Nicolau Saker Neto: I guess it would be H2SO4. But I am not quite sure.

Comment: Correct! Okay, so before you bubble air you have a solution of $\ce{H2SO3}$, and after bubbling air, it oxidizes to $\ce{H2SO4}$. Which of these is a stronger acid? What do you expect to happen to the solution pH after bubbling the air?

Comment: Btw, how does H2SO3 oxidises, what get reduce here?

Answer (score 5):

Upon adding $\ce{SO2}$ gas to water, it shows its *acidic oxide* character by hydrolyzing to sulfurous acid:

$$\ce{SO2(g) + H2O(l) <=> H2SO3(aq)}$$

$\ce{H2SO3}$ is a **weak** diprotic acid in water, with the following acid dissociation equilibria:

$$\ce{H2SO3(aq) <=> H+(aq) + HSO3^{-}(aq)}\ \ \ \ \ \mathrm{K_{a1}=1.4\times 10^{-2}}$$
$$\ce{HSO3{}^{-}(aq) <=> H+(aq) + SO3{}^{2-}(aq)}\ \ \ \ \ \mathrm{K_{a2}=6.3\times 10^{-8}}$$

Thus, addition of $\ce{SO2}$ gas to water will produce an acidic solution.

What would happen if air were bubbled into the solution? Air is a mixture of mostly nitrogen and oxygen. It so happens that $\ce{SO2}$ reacts with oxygen to form $\ce{SO3}$:

$$\ce{2SO2(g) + O2(g) -> 2SO3(g)}$$

Here, the sulfur atom in $\ce{SO2}$ is oxidized (oxidation number goes from +4 to +6) while the oxygen atoms in $\ce{O2}$ are reduced (oxidation number goes from 0 to -2). Now, $\ce{SO3}$ also happens to be an acidic oxide, and it hydrolyzes in water to form sulphuric acid:

$$\ce{SO3(g) + H2O(l) <=> H2SO4(aq)}$$

This time, $\ce{H2SO4}$ is a **strong** diprotic acid:

$$\ce{H2SO4(aq) <=>> H+(aq) + HSO4^{-}(aq)}\ \ \ \ \ \mathrm{K_{a1} \approx 10^6}$$
$$\ce{HSO4{}^{-}(aq) <=> H+(aq) + SO4{}^{2-}(aq)}\ \ \ \ \ \mathrm{K_{a2}=1\times 10^{-2}}$$

Assuming that not much $\ce{SO2}$ is lost while bubbling air through the sulphurous acid solution, then you're effectively *replacing a weak acid with a strong acid*, which would cause the pH to *decrease*.

As a final remark, if the sulphurous acid solution were bubbled with pure nitrogen, then there would be no oxidation of $\ce{SO2}$ into $\ce{SO3}$, and after a while enough $\ce{SO2}$ will have been dragged away for the solution to become a less concentrated sulphurous acid, which would therefore have a *higher* pH.

Comment: If I aerate the sulphurous  acid only with N2 ,why doesn't it convert SO2 to SO3, is it because of not having lower oxidation states for nitrogen, other-than zero?

Comment: Nitrogen can reach negative oxidation numbers, but that's irrelevant; without oxygen gas, $\ce{2SO2 + \color{Red}{O2} -> 2SO3}$ can't happen!

Comment: Here what happened to the oxygen.You have stated that it is reduced to -2 oxidation state.But where is it?

Comment: The oxygen gas was added to sulphur dioxide $\ce{SO2}$ to make sulphur *trioxide* $\ce{SO3}$. All oxygen atoms in both these compounds have an oxidation number of -2.

Comment: Okay, Could you state some other gases behave like this,and can't liquid and solids behave like the way SO2(g) did?

Comment: I can't think of another acidic/basic substance off the top of my head which will react and change its acidity/basicity by simply exposing it to air, though it's not really a special feature of sulphur oxides. It doesn't have to be a gas, either. The critical part of this question was the reaction with oxygen.

Comment: Okay , so what is the most important thing that I could get form this question?

Comment: That is, to a large extent, for you to decide. But some basic points are: (1) sulphur has more than one common oxide; (2) both sulphur oxides are acidic, and hydrolyze in water to create two different acids; (3) one oxide can be converted into the other by simple exposure ti oxygen; (4) atmospheric air is often a source of oxygen for oxidation reactions; (5) sulphuric acid is a much stronger acid than sulphurous acid; (6) comparing two solutions of different acids at the same concentration, the stronger acid will make a more acidic solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24796/discussion-between-on-the-way-to-success-and-nicolau-saker-neto).

Comment: Nicolau Saker Neto:So thank you for the help given to clear me this doubt.

Answer (score -1):

When you dissolve $\ce{SO2}$ in water you get $\ce{H2SO3}$. $\ce{SO2(aq)}$ means $\ce{H2SO3}$ therefor,the pH of the solution will be slightly acidic when compared to that of pure water.

to your other question.when you aerate the solution $\ce{SO2}$ gas right above the solution goes away.The equilibrium is then disturbed.Therefore, $\ce{SO2}$ dissolved in the solution comes out.Because of that pH of the solution increases.

Comment: This is incorrect! While bubbling an aqueous solution of a gas does remove some of it from the water, there is another effect to be taken into account in this case.

Comment: @ Nicolau Saker Neto:Actually SO2 is dissolved in water.I don't see any other effect to be taken in this case.Please let me know what the other effect is.

Comment: @lucyG The other effect is oxidation of $\ce{H2SO3}$ to $\ce{H2SO4}$ by oxygen in the air.

Comment: @bon Yes that effect can also be there.But according to the question of  On the way to success don't you think we have to give more priority to the equlibrium that has been made rather than other effects.In my point of view this question inquires about the basic knowledge of Le Chatlier's principle

Comment: @lucyG I don't see anything in the question that suggests we should ignore the effect of oxidation.